# Java 8 lambda expression for finding "contains"

Tags: java, list, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a method that takes `List<String> locations` as a parameter. I am populating a list of users in the same method based on a particular condition. Now what I want is, the user should be present in this locations. In short, the user is valid iff user's location is present in the list of locations provided. locations.

This is my current code:

```
primaryList.stream()
        .filter(some_pattern_matching)[.MATCH THE LOCATION HERE]
        .map(user -> user.getNames())
        .collect(toList())
```

is there any way to say `locations.contains(user -> user.getLocation())` OR
`user -> user.getLocation().isPresentIn(locations)` OR have locations converted into one more stream and then do matching?

This is my current code:

```
 .filter(locations.stream().filter(loc -> loc.equalsIgnoreCase(s.getLocation())))
```

which of course does not compile.

Comment: Could you provide some minimal working example of your code?

Comment: *the user is valid iff user's location is present in the list of locations provided*: so, `boolean userIsValid = locations.contains(user.getLocation())`? Is that what you want? If not, provide the method you want to implement, with its arguments, return type, and javadoc, because it's quite unclear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean this:

```
.filter(user -> locations.contains(user.getLocation())
```

Comment: This is case senstive. What he is doing is case senstive check